# SQL using MIN with CHAR content in SELECT()

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following data (field varchar(55)):

```
123,00
212,11
1.212,00
```

With

```
SELECT MIN(FIELD) FROM XYZ
```

I get "1.212,00". This is wrong for me, but not wrong for MySQL.
I need the following: 123,00.

How can I do this without changing the field type?

TIA Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) your char value to numeric value.

```
select min(
              CAST( replace(
                      replace ( FIELD, '.', '' ),
                      ',', '.'
                    )
                   AS DECIMAL(5,2))
           )  ...
```

Comment: With replace I get 1112,00 if MIN is over 1000. But there should be 1.112,00. How to get this?

Comment: FORMAT(XYZ, 2) before MIN(...) Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cast` or `Convert`:

The CONVERT() and CAST() functions take a value of one type and produce a value of another type.

`SELECT MIN(CAST(Field AS DECIMAL(10,2))) FROM XYZ`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: Im a SQL Server guy so that was a wild guess, just replace it with a valid numeric data type and edit the post to meet your needs.  Try decimal.

Comment: Thanks for your help. User danihp described the correct way. Without replacing ',' and '.' it will not work like I want it.